Purchasing land
I'm asking for advice on buying a piece of land in a mountainous region in Alaska where I could build a cabin for vacationing. I'm thinking about 2 acres.
The Listings from realators that I have seen show only parcels in flat areas.  What I want is a location with wild beautiful views.

Call real estate agents in the general area you are interested in. If they don’t list unimproved land they may well know who does.

What COUNTRY or countries you are considering.  USA?  If USA, would you consider some parts of Canada?  If in the USA, where -- Adirondacks?  Rocky mountains?  Sierra Nevada?  Or where?  Do you want land above timberline?  Land you have to mule-pack into?  Or land with a good access road and the conveniences of modern life (e.g., library, a medical facility, a large-ish store) accessible with a, say, 30 minute drive?   If you have difficulty answering these questions, you need to do some research, starting with reading, and then progressing to inspecting areas by travelling to them.

Yes, my mistake. I didn't mention the location where I am searching: looking to build a small cabin in Alaska for recreational purposes. Maybe around 2 acres for up to $15k. The listings from realtors only show parcels in flat areas. I have no interest in building a cabin in such areas, but only looking for places with attractive interesting views.

Again, pertinent comments from ab2, I am not looking for access to modern conveniences. But am seeking a wild beautiful view more than anything else.

The OP has narrowed her original post considerably.  She is interested in buying a small lot (maybe around 2 acres) with wild, beautiful, mountaineous views where she could build a small vacation cabin.  Her budget is modest.
This resonates with me.  How wonderful to be young, energetic, adventurous and in love with the wild!
It is unclear how much she has searched.  She mentions "listings from realators" which show only "parcels in flat areas."  I did a very quick, cursory search on Google, and what I saw pretty much agreed with that, although not totally, with the added disadvantage of many the parcels being larger and more expensive than what the OP wants.
What would I do?
First, I would do a thorough Google search and get in contact with the sellers who seem most promising.  This will entail a lot of e-mails, texts and phone calls, but my impression is that Alaskans are helpful people.
Second, I would arrange a trip to Alaska, in the season(s) when I planned to use the cabin, to find out if I really, truly wanted an Alaskan vacation house.  My apologies to the OP if she already knows, from experience, what living in Alaska is like.
Third, I would research how much it would cost to build a cabin in a mountaineous area in Alaska, and also assess my skills in repairing and fixing everything that can go wrong on such a property (plumbing, electrical, carpentry, auto repair, etc).
Finally, depending on the results of the above research, I might do some research on locations one step down from the remoteness and wildness of Alaska, although wildfires which will only increase in frequency and intensity are making the Western US Lower 48 less attractive than even 10 years ago.
Some of this may sound condescending.  This is not my intention. I envy the OP and respect her drive!  Nor is it my intention to throw cold water on the OP's marvelous project. What the OP wants is achievable, but there is no point in minimizing the work involved.

I would also watch the movie Land

IMO there are plenty of excellent sites on flat land with very good views of mountains and even river/lake at the same time. However, don't let that put you off finding a mountain site to put your cabin.
Alaska Public Land (.org site) states that there are currently 3 ways you can acquire public land in Alaska. Obviously you can also acquire private land if it is for sale - as you seem to have been investigating.
In the following you should note that the annual sealed bids and remote recreation cabin sites staking program are currently for ALASKAN RESIDENTS ONLY
To three types from the site linked above, which I've updated with current sales:

Annual “Sealed-bid” Land Auctions: Currently (July 2024) 207 sites available by sealed bid, of which 35 are under $15,000. For Alaskan residents only!


Over-the-counter land sales: Open to both Alaskan residents and non-residents. Currently (July 2024) no packages for sale

Remote Recreational Cabin Sites Staking Program: Open to Alaska residents only. To quote the RRCS site:



This year (2024), 2 areas are being offered: East Fork Pass II, approximately
40 miles east of Nome along the Nome-Council Road and Aniak-Doestock
II, approximately 5 miles east of Aniak, near the Confluence of
Doestock Creek and the Aniak River, in the vicinity of the lower
Kuskokwim River. In order to purchase a parcel in this program, you
must apply in the drawing, win a staking authorization, stake a parcel
on the ground, submit a lease application, enter a 3-year lease, make
lease payments (while the parcel is surveyed and appraised), and at
the end of the lease you may purchase the parcel.

How mountainous you like your mountains is up to you too - currently most of the above are not very in my opinion, but some are in what I would describe as forested hilly areas.
There is also an agricultural and program by sealed bid, but you won't be interested in that.

Thanks for the realistic well researched reply. I agree: flat land with views of mountains yes, but not land in the mountains.
